# Unable to start laravel-echo-server using supervisor

Tags: linux, laravel, supervisord

My project is located in `/var/www/html/bcbAPI`. The `laravel-echo-server.json` file is located in `usr/bin`

My `laravel-worker.conf` file

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/bcbAPI/artisan queue:work --queue="emails, queue, queue2" --tries=1  --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/bcbAPI/storage/logs/worker.log

[program:laravel-worker2]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)03d
command=/usr/bin/laravel-echo-server laravel-echo-server start --dir=/var/www/html/bcbAPI
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/bcbAPI/storage/logs/echoserver.log
stderr_logfile=/var/www/html/bcbAPI/storage/logs/echoserver-error.log
```

Other ways I've tried

```
[program:laravel-worker2]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)03d
directory=/var/www/html/bcbAPI
command=/usr/bin/laravel-echo-server start
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/bcbAPI/storage/logs/echoserver.log
```

Running supervisor

```
sudo supervisorctl reread

sudo supervisorctl update

sudo supervisorctl start laravel-worker:*
```

The log file is empty. What am I doing wrong? I can start the server if I'm in the `usr/bin` directory

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install laravel-echo-server globally [see here for more detail](https://medium.com/@dennissmink/laravel-echo-server-how-to-24d5778ece8b) and `laravel-echo-server.json`should place in your project root directory.

Then you need to create two supervisor configuration. One for queue and another for laravel echo server like bellow:

laravel-queue-worker.conf

```
[program:laravel-queue-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s
command=php **project_absolute_path**/artisan horizon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=rana
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/laravel-queue-worker.log
```

laravel-echo-server.conf

```
[program:laravel-echo-server]
process_name=%(program_name)s
command=laravel-echo-server start --dir=**project_absolute_path**
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=rana
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/laravel-echo-server.log
```

**Project Absolute Path example: `/var/www/html/laravel` **